# Выпадающее меню накладывается на себя

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend

Пытался сделать выпадающее меню , однако при наведении - сабменю не хочет корректно отображаться справа от основного .

http://jsfiddle.net/pnca41qz/

```css
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.all {
  background-image: url(../img/shopORDER1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  flex-grow: 2;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
}

.OTSTUP {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Marck Script", cursive;
  line-height: 140%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.top-right {
  font-size: 2.3em;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: #C0F400;
}

.top-left {
  float: left;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu ul,
.menu ol {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu>ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu>ul li {
  position: relative;
  border-right: 2px solid #403FD7;
}

.menu>ul li a {
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px 35px 15px 45px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #454448;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.menu>ul li:first-child {
  border-left: 2px solid #403F89;
}

.menu>ul li:last-child {
  border-right: 2px solid #403F89;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  background: #403F89;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px -5px #1A72E6;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

header img {
  width: 60px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 4em;
  font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto\9;
}

header,
#footer {
  width: 98%;
  background-color: #403F89;
}

header {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 1%;
}

#footer {
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  margin-top: 12px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
  font-size: 1em;
}

a {
  color: #C524D3;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all.5s ease;
}

a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all.5s ease;
}

.all a {
  color: #E382FF;
}

.all a:hover {
  color: #C0F400;
}

a:active {
  color: #C4FFFF;
}


/* MENUSHKA */

.menu li ul {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 150px;
  display: none;
}

.menu li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.menu li>ul li {
  border: 1px solid #1A72E6;
}

.menu li>ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: none;
  background: #1A70E3;
}

.menu li>ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  right: -250px;
  top: 0;
}


/*  Videlenie  */

 ::selection {
  background: #FFDEE3;
  color: #000000;
   ::-moz-selection {
    background: #FFDEE3;
    color: #000000;
     ::-webkit-selection {
      background: #FFDEE3;
      color: #000000;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <base target="_blank">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <title>Заказ</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main2.css">
  <link href="img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <header>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat" rel="stylesheet">
      <div class="logo">
        <span class="top-left"> <a href=""> <img src="img/VK.png" alt="" title="Группа ВК"> </a> </span>
        <a href="Order.html" target="_self" title="Страница заказа"> Заказ </a>
      </div>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
      <a href="About.html" target="_self" title="Полезная информация о нашем магазине" class="top-right"> О нас </a>
      <a href="Main.html" target="_self" title="Главная страница магазина" class="top-right"> Кнопка </a>
    </header>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
    <div class="all">
      <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#"> Простыни </a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Подушки </a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">50x70cm</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Караван</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Бамбук ЭКО</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">ТЧ Бамбук</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Шарм</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Люкс</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Прима</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Диалог</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Классика</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Пуховая</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Полупуховая</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Green Line Хлопок</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Green Line Лён</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Verossa Camel</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Verossa Aloe Vera</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Verossa Classic</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">SPAtex</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Коллекция 750</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Коллекция 960 с бортиком</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Коллекция 925 со вставкой MEMORY</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Коллекция 875 с валиком</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Коллекция 916 двухкамерная</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Эвкалипт</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Лебяжий пух</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">ГАРМОНИЯ</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Стандарт</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Эконом</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Перо-пуховая подушка "Неженка"</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">70x70cm</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">ТЧ Бамбук</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Полу-пуховая</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Green Line Лён</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Green Line Хлопок</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Verossa Camel</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Verossa Aloe Vera</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Verossa Classic</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">SPAtex</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Коллекция 750</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Коллекция 960 с бортиком</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Коллекция 875 с валиком</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Эвкалипт</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Шарм</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Неженка</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Люкс</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Прима</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Диалог</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Лебяжий пух</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">ГАРМОНИЯ</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Стандарт</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Эконом</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Классика</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Пуховая</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Караван</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Эко</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">70x71cm</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"> Наволочки </a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"> Пледы </a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"> Одеяла </a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"> Наматрацники </a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"> Комплекты </a> </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <p class="OTSTUP"> Как только Вы выбрали , что покупать - свяжитесь с нами по номеру телефона
        <a href="tel:"></a> или
        <a href="tel:"></a>! </p>
      <p class="OTSTUP"> Или свяжитесь с нами в <a href=""> нашей группе ВКонтакте! </a> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    Все права защищены. Копирование информации и использование в коммерческих целях преследуется по закону &copy; 2018
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно для `.menu li > ul li ul` задать фиксированную ширину, например `width: 250px;`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.all {
  background-image: url(../img/shopORDER1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  flex-grow: 2;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
}

.OTSTUP {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Marck Script", cursive;
  line-height: 140%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.top-right {
  font-size: 2.3em;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: #C0F400;
}

.top-left {
  float: left;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu ul,
.menu ol {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu>ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu>ul li {
  position: relative;
  border-right: 2px solid #403FD7;
}

.menu>ul li a {
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px 35px 15px 45px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #454448;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.menu>ul li:first-child {
  border-left: 2px solid #403F89;
}

.menu>ul li:last-child {
  border-right: 2px solid #403F89;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  background: #403F89;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px -5px #1A72E6;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

header img {
  width: 60px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 4em;
  font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto\9;
}

header,
#footer {
  width: 98%;
  background-color: #403F89;
}

header {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 1%;
}

#footer {
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  margin-top: 12px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
  font-size: 1em;
}

a {
  color: #C524D3;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all.5s ease;
}

a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all.5s ease;
}

.all a {
  color: #E382FF;
}

.all a:hover {
  color: #C0F400;
}

a:active {
  color: #C4FFFF;
}


/* MENUSHKA */

.menu li ul {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 150px;
  display: none;
}

.menu li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.menu li>ul li {
  border: 1px solid #1A72E6;
}

.menu li>ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: none;
  background: #1A70E3;
}

.menu li>ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  right: -250px;
  width: 250px;
  top: 0;
}


/*  Videlenie  */

 ::selection {
  background: #FFDEE3;
  color: #000000;
   ::-moz-selection {
    background: #FFDEE3;
    color: #000000;
     ::-webkit-selection {
      background: #FFDEE3;
      color: #000000;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <base target="_blank">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <title>Заказ</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main2.css">
  <link href="img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <header>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat" rel="stylesheet">
      <div class="logo">
        <span class="top-left"> <a href=""> <img src="img/VK.png" alt="" title="Группа ВК"> </a> </span>
        <a href="Order.html" target="_self" title="Страница заказа"> Заказ </a>
      </div>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
      <a href="About.html" target="_self" title="Полезная информация о нашем магазине" class="top-right"> О нас </a>
      <a href="Main.html" target="_self" title="Главная страница магазина" class="top-right"> Кнопка </a>
    </header>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
    <div class="all">
      <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#"> Простыни </a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Подушки </a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">50x70cm</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Караван</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Бамбук ЭКО</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">ТЧ Бамбук</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Шарм</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Люкс</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Прима</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Диалог</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Классика</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Пуховая</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Полупуховая</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Green Line Хлопок</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Green Line Лён</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Verossa Camel</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Verossa Aloe Vera</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Verossa Classic</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">SPAtex</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Коллекция 750</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Коллекция 960 с бортиком</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Коллекция 925 со вставкой MEMORY</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Коллекция 875 с валиком</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Коллекция 916 двухкамерная</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Эвкалипт</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Лебяжий пух</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">ГАРМОНИЯ</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Стандарт</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Эконом</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Перо-пуховая подушка "Неженка"</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">70x70cm</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">ТЧ Бамбук</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Полу-пуховая</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Green Line Лён</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Green Line Хлопок</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Verossa Camel</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Verossa Aloe Vera</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Verossa Classic</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">SPAtex</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Коллекция 750</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Коллекция 960 с бортиком</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Коллекция 875 с валиком</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Эвкалипт</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Шарм</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Неженка</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Люкс</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Прима</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Диалог</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Лебяжий пух</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">ГАРМОНИЯ</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Стандарт</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Эконом</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Классика</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Пуховая</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Караван</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Эко</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">70x71cm</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"> Наволочки </a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"> Пледы </a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"> Одеяла </a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"> Наматрацники </a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"> Комплекты </a> </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <p class="OTSTUP"> Как только Вы выбрали , что покупать - свяжитесь с нами по номеру телефона
        <a href="tel:"></a> или
        <a href="tel:"></a>! </p>
      <p class="OTSTUP"> Или свяжитесь с нами в <a href=""> нашей группе ВКонтакте! </a> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    Все права защищены. Копирование информации и использование в коммерческих целях преследуется по закону &copy; 2018
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```